# How can I count the number of occurrences of the character '/' in a C string?

Tags: c, string

How can I count the number of occurrences in a C string of `/` ?

I can do this:

```
int countSlash(char str[])
{
    int count = 0, k = 0;
    while (str[k] != '\0')
    {
          if (str[k] == '/')
              count++;
          k++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

But this is not an elegant way; any suggestions on how to improve it?

Comment: Yours is elegant enough IMO...

Comment: The main criticism might be the rather specialized interface compared with `int countChar(char const *str, char c)`, which (a) promises not to modify the string it is passed, and (b) can be used to count asterisks, blanks, etc with essentially no loss of efficiency.  You can write a simple function `int countSlash(char const *str) { return countChar(str, '/'); }` if you really want the less general interface.  There's a decent chance the compiler will optimize that for you if inlining etc is enabled.

Comment: Elegance, could be in many different ways. It may be the shortest, or the most readable, or the most easily understood. And the most readable, could also be the most unreadable to other person. Therefore, the 'Elegance', is a subjective thought. Maybe you should ask for the most EFFICIENT way, in terms of speed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) would make a smaller loop:

```
ptr = str;

while ((ptr = strchr(ptr '/')) != NULL)
    count++, ptr++;
```

I should add that I don't endorse brevity for brevity's sake, and I'll always opt for the *clearest* expression, all other things being equal. I do find the `strchr` loop more *elegant*, but the original implementation in the question is clear and lives inside a function, so I don't prefer one over the other, so long as they both pass unit tests.

Comment: True, but there's no good reason to write code like that in the 21st Century!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth HA perhaps so. I don't have a problem with this sort of 1-liner in standard C, but then again loops like this don't often end up in my own code.

Comment: How would a 21st Century C Coder write the code, @OliCharlesworth?  I'm a 20th Century C Coder who's still working; what pb2q has written looks OK to me as the body of the `countSlash()` function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I have an inherent dislike of overly-compressed code that emulates the conventions espoused in e.g. K&R (in this case, assignment and conditionals on the same line).  That may have made sense when terminals were small and compilers were bad, but not so much anymore.  But obviously, it's a taste thing.  (Having said that, I've just seen slashmais's answer, and that's an even worse example of what I'm talking about!)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I really can't say there's a problem with assigning within an expression, it is a language feature after all, and IMO very simple to read and understand. On the other hand, I dislike the convention of being "overly verbose" which I find that makes code hard to read when taking a quick glance at a few lines. Need to jump back and forth because everything is scattered around. Not good. :)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: so what would you write instead?  `char *ptr = strchr(str, '/'); while (ptr != NULL) ptr = strchr(ptr, '/');`?  This writes the call to `strchr()` twice, which violates the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.

Comment: @pb2q: Do you have an infinite loop if there's a slash in the string because you keep searching from the position that contained the last slash?

Comment: @zxcdw: As I said, it's a taste thing. (IMHO, the existence of a language feature doesn't mean that it has to be used).  But I dislike overly-verbose code too; it's a balancing act.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good catch, edited the loop to make the code even more obtuse...

Comment: I think you need to think a bit harder...because I think you've got undefined behaviour (though there are sequence points lurking around the function call, but I'd be leery of that increment), but anyway the incremented pos will be overwritten with the unincremented value returned from `strchr()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I haven't thought about it.  But the fact that the pb2q is still trying to get this right is a hint that this isn't the most readable way this functionality could be achieved...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: That I agree with; the original question is clear and correct.  Dinking with incrementing the pointer is a nuisance, and defeats the clarity that the `strchr()` rewrite appeared to offer.

Answer (score 2):

Yours is good enough. Maybe, this would look prettier to some:

```
int countSlash(char * str)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (; *str != 0; ++str)
    {
        if (*str == '/')
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generic interface, obvious approach, appropriate types and purely idiomatic expressions:

```
size_t str_count_char(const char *s, int c)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    while (s && *s)
         if (*s++ == c)
             ++count;

    return count;
}
```

Oli Charlesworth would probably raise concerns regarding assignments and conditionals on the same line, but I think it's fairly well hidden  ;-)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think your loop invariant can be simplified down to simply `while (*s)`. It should only be necessary to check that `s` is not a `NULL` pointer at the very beginning of execution.

Comment: @GregE.: You're right, checking for `NULL` is required at most once here. I firmly believe that the compiler is smarter than me, hence I'm relying on the compiler to optimize this away. It should be easy since we're not modifying `s` anywhere in this function.

Comment: @Philip, possibly, but given that it's redundant and makes the loop costlier, why not just move it to a containing `if` statement? Incidentally, I notice most of the solutions on this page don't bother checking for a `NULL` pointer and jump right to dereferencing the string, which could cause undefined behavior, so kudos for not doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
int count=0;
char *s=str;
while (*s) count += (*s++ == '/');
```

Comment: Why no spaces? Why the cast?  Why not just `n += (*s++ == '/');`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, it would be easier on the eye ;) - the cast: because the str[] is an array and not a string, and this is C

Comment: @slashmais, I'm pretty sure that the explicit cast is totally redundant. It's been a long time since I've done any real coding in C, but, as I recall, when you pass a variable referencing an array it automatically gets demoted to a pointer to the first element of said array. Hence `char str[]` and `char *str` should be completely interchangeable for all intents and purposes.

Comment: `char *s=str;` is valid C code. You don't really need do a cast. And the ternary operator usage here is redundant. `(*s++ == '/')` will return `0´(false) or `1`(true) anyway. You are doing something like this: `(1 || 0)?1:0`;

Comment: @Jack: Thanks, goes to show how C++ (bool-type) messes with straight thinking in C - changing my answer accordingly :)